# Regex for at least three 1's and at most four 0's

Tags: regular-expressions

The alphabet is {0,1}, express all finite strings containing at least three 1's and at most four 0's.

---

I've come up with a method that enumerate every possible number of 0's:

$$111^{+}+0111^{+}+1^{+}011^{+}+111^{+}01^{*}+00111^{+}+......$$
But for three 1's and four 0's this is far too complex.

Need some help.

Comment: I suggest you try constructing a DFA for it and then convert it into its equivalent regex. I believe that would be easier, though an extended procedure.

Comment: I am taught to build regex first and convert it to NFA then DFA(which is easier than regex=>DFA). I can't image how to construct DFA and conversely get regex. Could you show me how?

Comment: Hint: make states which keep track of the number of 0s and 1s seen so far up to 4, connect appropriately and mark the right ones as accepted.

Comment: It's not clear to me that your "..." even describes a finite object, and all regular expressions are finite strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for at least $a$ 1’s and at most $b$ 0’s:
$$
\sum_{a_0+\cdots+a_b=a} 1^{a_0}1^*\prod_{i=1}^b (\epsilon+0)1^{a_i}1^*,
$$
where $a_0,\ldots,a_b \geq 0$ are integers. For example, when $a=b=2$ we get
$$
\begin{align*}
&111^*(\epsilon+0)1^*(\epsilon+0)1^*+\\
&1^*(\epsilon+0)111^*(\epsilon+0)1^*+\\
&1^*(\epsilon+0)1^*(\epsilon+0)111^*+\\
&11^*(\epsilon+0)11^*(\epsilon+0)1^*+\\
&11^*(\epsilon+0)1^*(\epsilon+0)11^*+\\
&1^*(\epsilon+0)11^*(\epsilon+0)11^*.
\end{align*}
$$
With more effort, you can even create an unambiguous regular expression, that is, one which corresponds to a UFA rather than an NFA; in other words, whenever there is a sum, the corresponding languages are disjoint. As an example, here is an unambiguous regular expression corresponding to $a=b=1$:
$$
1^*+11^*01^*+011^*.
$$
Compare this to the ambiguous one constructed above:
$$
11^*(\epsilon+0)1^*+1^*(\epsilon+0)11^*.
$$
The words $1,101$ are both captured in both summands above, but in only a single summand in the unambiguous regular expression.